# Calculating non-zero values using SAS

Tags: sas, sum, cumulative-sum

I have the following data. The Amount for Limit variable is available only for first record

If the Limit is 0 then PostBal should be same as Balance, otherwise it sum of Limit+Balance

```
   Id        date              Limit          Balance
   101      4/1/2019        0         50
   101      4/1/2019                 120
   101      4/2/2019                 150
   102      4/1/2019        100   100
   102      4/1/2019                    50
   102      4/2/2019                    25
```

Desired result:

```
   Id        date           Limit      Balance  PostBal
   101      4/1/2019        0            50             50
   101      4/1/2019                    120          120   
   101      4/2/2019                    150          150
   102      4/1/2019       100       100           200
   102      4/1/2019                      50          250
   102      4/2/2019                      25          275
```

My code:

```
    Data want;
     Set have;
    By id date;
    if first.date and not first.id then Limit=PostBal;
    If first.date then do;
     PostBal=Limit;
   End;
   PostBal+Balance;
 Run;
```

This is working fine if the Limit is >0 but not for Limit=0. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I don;t understand.  Why don't you want running totals for ID 101?  Is it because LIMIT is zero?

Comment: Yes. If the Limit is zero then PostBal is always the Balance amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the fact that LIMIT is zero so that you can use that fact to change how PostBal is calculated. So make a new variable for that.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id ;
  if first.id then limit_copy =limit;
  retain limit_copy;
  if first.id then PostBal=limit;
  if limit_copy ne 0 then PostBal+Balance;
  else postbal=balance;
run;
```